# Unknow Swift Error String Error

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Hi I'm struggling with debugging this error from swift. Is occurring in 15-20% of the cases.

```
String Error: #0 public_html/my/library/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(392): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->readLine(NULL)
#1 public_html/my/library/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(269): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_getFullResponse(NULL)
#2 public_html/my/library/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(222): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM: <inf...', Array, Array)
#3 public_html/my/library/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(304): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM: <inf...', Array)
#4 public_html/my/library/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(408): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doMailFromCommand('info@test.com')
#5 public_html/my/library/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(436): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doMailTransaction(Object(Swift_Message), 'info@test.com', Array, Array)
#6 public_html/my/library/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(169): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_sendTo(Object(Swift_Message), 'info@test.com', Array, Array)
#7 public_html/my/library/Swift/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(82): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#8 public_html/my/scripts/email_cron.php(195): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message))
#9 {main}
Line: 156
File: public_html/my/library/Swift/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
```

It says it is an String Error, however, what does that mean? Is the mail server unavailable?

Comment: What code is causing this error?

Comment: Is this a long-running php script? I've seen this error (or something like it...) before with a long-running script that lost the connection to the smtp server somewhere along the line...

Comment: @jeroen it is running for max 20-30 seconds. Sends the emails in batches of 50 in a row.

Comment: Sometimes there is another error, that starts with:  Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->_getReadHandle()